# WaitNamedPipe just hangs

Tags: c++, c, windows, named-pipes

I'm having trouble with the WaitNamedPipe function hanging. ...this the portion of my code relevant to the problem.  I created a process, then a pipe, and the function WaitNamedPipe seems to be stuck on FALSE and therefore hangs.   The function waitnamedpipe waits for the CC process to initiate.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION po;
STARTUPINFO s;

GetStartupInfo (&s);

if(CreateProcess ("c:\\s2.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &s, &po) == FALSE)
{
    printf("Error %d starting CC\n", GetLastError());
    exit(-1);
}


HANDLE pipe=CreateNamedPipe ("\\.\pipe\CC-"+po.dwProcessId, 0x00000003, 0x40000000, 
                               0x00080000L, 0x00000004, 128, 0, NULL);

while (WaitNamedPipe ("\\.\pipe\CC-"+po.dwProcessId, INFINITE) == FALSE )
    Sleep (300);
```

*edit  I changed it up some..However it still hangs

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION po; STARTUPINFO s;
GetStartupInfo (&s);
if(CreateProcess ("c:\\s2.exe", NULL,
                   NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &s,
                   &po) == FALSE) {
     printf("Error %d starting CC\n", GetLastError());
     exit(-1);
 }

HANDLE pipe=CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name, 0x00000003,
                           FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
                           PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,128, 128, 0,
                           NULL);

while(WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, INFINITE)==FALSE)
Sleep(300);

HANDLE CC = CreateFile (pipe_name,
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL);

bool fConnected =  ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL) ?  TRUE :
                           (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED); 

if(fConnected)  printf("true"); else  printf("false");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing client and server sides of the named pipe. The server (vendor of the pipe) will call [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a pipe. Then, to wait for clients, it can call [ConnectNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Though beware, if a client connected to it already before this call, it will just return immediately with GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED.)

The client side can call [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Not CreateNamedPipe) to open an instance. If that fails, it means the server instance isn't available, so the client can call [WaitNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get notified of when one is available.

A good reference on MSDN is the [Named Pipe Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example, and the [Multithreaded Pipe Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example.

Edit: All the problems Jerry points out are true. I am pointing out the 'pipe logic' that he's referring to.

Comment: +1: As you can probably guess from the tone of my reply, it seemed like something looked wrong, but it's been so long since I used named pipes, I couldn't immediately put my finger on what. It looks like you've covered it quite nicely though.

Answer (score 3):

You may have others, but two problems are right here:

```
"\\.\pipe\CC-"+po.dwProcessId
```

First, the back-slash character acts as an escape character in C and C++ strings, so you need two backslashes in your source code to give one backslash in the string itself. So, for the start, your string needs to be:

```
"\\\\.\\pipe\\CC-"
```

The second problem is with the `+po.dwProcessId` part. The `"\\.\pipe\CC-"` part gives a pointer to the beginning of a static string. You're then adding the value of `dwProcessId` to that pointer. If your process ID happens to be a number that's smaller than the string, that'll give a pointer to later in the string (e.g., if it happened to be 2, it would produce a pointer to `".\\pipe\\CC-"`, skipping over the two leading backslashes. If (as will more often be the case) the process ID happens to be a number larger that the length of the string, you'll get a pointer to some memory you don't own at all and have no idea what it might contain.

That means the name you're giving to `CreateNamedPipe` is essentially certain to be invalid. Since it fails to create the named pipe, `WaitNamedPipe` will immediately return false -- exactly the behavior you've observed.

You could try something more like this:

```
char pipe_name[32];
sprintf(pipe_name, "\\\\.\\pipe\\CC-%d", po.dwProcessId);

HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name, /* ... */);

WaitNamedPipe(pipe, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
```

I haven't tested it, but that should stand at least a little chance of being a bit closer to working. I'm not at all sure your named pipe logic is right yet, but at least this should get you to the point that you can start to work on it in a meaningful way.